# Monotouch: Slide-in new UIViewController

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, uiwindow

In AppDelegate I create a UIWindow.

Later in my program, I wan to create a new UIWindow and slide it in from right to left (like animate).

Here's my code from creating the new window:

```
UIWindow _tabWindow;
UITabBarController _tabBar;

_tabBar = new UITabBarController ();
_tabWindow = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds); 
_tabWindow.RootViewController = _tabBar;
_tabWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
```

How can I slide it in?

Thanks!

Mojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typically an application has only one UIWindow instance. The UIWindow is like the glass of the screen if I may use the comparison, or the frame of your application.

You should look for creating other views, these views will appear and disappear and are managed by a view controller.

Comment: I have a UINavigationController in my AppDelegate, but as far as I know Apple guidelines doesn't allow an UITabBarController to be pushed to a UINavigationController right? So I'm very confused how to make my app start up with a list of servers, the user click a server and then a UITabBarController shows up. So I wanted to create a second UIWindow for the UITabBarController and show it on top of the main UIWindow.

Comment: Your AppDelegate (or another main controller if you want so) should take that in charge and switch from the navigation controller (or UITableViewController : [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ) to the UITabBarController. The controller in use will then show and manage the view(s).

Comment: And how do I animate ... slide in ... and out ... between the UITableViewController and the UITabBarController? Thanks for helping me!!!! :)